# Apache2's SVN module not working after upgrade

Tags: apache-http-server, svn, ubuntu-14.04

My operating system (Ubuntu 14.04) upgraded (via apt upgrade) apache2 from 2.4.7 to 2.4.10.

After the upgrade, apache2 does not start anymore.
In particular, the problem is the SVN module.

The reported error is the following:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 143 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so: undefined symbol: ap_hook_force_authn

If I explicitly exclude the SVN module, everything (except SVN) works fine: apache2 starts correctly and every other website is up and running.

I already tried to remove and re-install the libapache2-svn package without success (purge & install).

I honestly do not know what to do. The problem seems related to the *mod_authz_svn.so* binary which is (probably) not compatible anymore with apache 2.4.10.

Any suggestion is really appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Right now, the only "fix" which worked was to downgrade Apache to 2.4.7. It seems a known bug which was never fixed. https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000068185-Cannot-install-Subversion-on-Ubuntu-with-Apache-2-4-10-undefined-symbol-ap-hook-force-authn